# Python: Can't change a dictionary field while iterating over it

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, foreach

I have this list:

```
>>> stud
[19, 11, 6, 26]
```

If I loop over the `'draws'` field, I get the following:

```
>>> [aluDict[str(s)]['draws'] for s in stud]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Now I want to add `1` to each of those, so as to obtain (potentially) the following:

```
>>> [aluDict[str(s)]['draws'] for s in stud]
[2, 1, 2, 1]
```

In order to do so, I tried this:

```
>>> [aluDict[str(s)]['draws']+=1 for s in stud]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [aluDict[str(s)]['draws']+=1 for s in stud]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I do it individually, I can accomplish that:

```
>>> aluDict[str(19)]['draws']
2
>>> aluDict[str(19)]['draws']+=1
>>> aluDict[str(19)]['draws']
3
```

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have assignments in list comprehensions (yet).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the list `[2, 1, 2, 1]` and don't want to actually change any of the values stored in `aluDict`, use `+1`:

```
[aluDict[str(s)]['draws']+1 for s in stud]
```

Comment: Obviously, but I think the idea was to update those values.